# A possible way vs. a possibility

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between the following questions?

```
 1. Is there another possible way of saying it?
```

vs.

```
 2. Is there another possibility of saying it?
```

The difference between the two isn't merely stylistic, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not a native speaker, but I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

Yeah, the difference isn't just stylistic. In the fist sentence "Is there another possible way of saying it?" you're basically asking if there are other alternatives of the word or a sentence, regarding the same meaning or the other way of pronouncing it (though this one isn't likely the case).
"Is there another possibility of saying it?" - this sentence seems to be less correct, because the word possibility refers to "a thing that may happen or be the case" so it doesn't much refer to what you're asking whereas the word "possible" could be appropriate, but it needs the additional noun next to it, which in the prior sentence is "way".
So I think the only difference is that the first one is correct and the next one isn't or just not as much. I'm not sure. I hope there'll appear more precise/explicit answers to your question because I just read my writing and it doesn't seem helpful at all.

P. S. It's my first answer on this website and as you see, I still need some more practise. I hope I'll improve in some time though.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your first post.